# How to detect corner with specific angle degree

Tags: opencv, image-processing, feature-detection, corner-detection

I have an image with a equilateral triangle and a rectangle:
[image: equilateral triangle and a rectangle]
And I want to detect 3 corner of the triangle only. I follow the [OpenCV Harris corner detector tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/harris_detector/harris_detector.html) I see that all the corner-point of the triangle have the threshold = 80 (when all the 4 corner-point of the rectangle threshold = 255). But I did not find the link between threshold and degree.

How can I find the corner that in the range of [55,65] degree, for example?
Here is the output Mat http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=qNidEAG0

P/s: I very new to CV, hope you can give some more detail!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that I found possible solution. I've implemented it on Mathematica and able to explain basic steps.

1. Use find corners operator and take strongest corners. Use Harris operator.
   [image: Corners]
2. Find contours (cv::FindContours).

   [image: Contours]
3. For each corner in each contour draw a circle and find point of intersection between circle and contour. There is no ready function for it in OpenCV and you should implement it yourself.

   [image: Intersections]
4. Now for each corner you have coordinates of three points: corner, and two points on sides of contour. It is enough to evaluate angles using [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_product):

   [image: angle estimation]

Result:

[image: Corners found]

Comment: For the first step, you mean is find all the local maxima of the result form the *cv::cornerHarris*?

Comment: Great solution! 
I think that the easiest way to find points of intersections in point 3 is to draw circles on empty (blank) image and the use & operator on this image and on image of contours. The result should be all points of intersections.

Comment: This didn't works when distance between contours is less than circles radius. In this cases you get a lot of false intersections.

Comment: @brotherofken - yo are right, but it's easy to fix - just draw each circle on separate image or find the smallest distance between corners and use smaller radius.